# Change text in order received page from woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is probably super easy, but I cannot find where to change this text here in the woocommerce check out page:

See this screenshot:[image]

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Has anybody figured out how to do this with the new WooCommerce version? My folder in plugins/woocommerce/checkout only has four files:
- form-checkout.php, form-coupon.php, form-login.php, terms.php

Answer (score 20):

You can refer to: [image]

This is where each piece of text comes on the Thank you page. This is part of a detailed post I wrote at: https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-customize-the-woocommerce-thank-you-page/ .

I hope this helps.

Comment: The screenshot with its labels was hugely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can find Order-details page here -

**Go to this path**

`wp-content -> plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> order -> order-details.php.`

into this page you can get **Order Details** .

Answer (score 2):

Go to this path.

```
wp-content -> plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> checkout
```

On this location you can get all the files for checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

Having just looked this up, I can confirm the correct location is:

```
plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php
```